# Conditional where clause in firestore queries

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have fetch some data from firestore but in my query I want to add a conditional where clause. I am using async-await for api and not sure how to add a consitional where clause.

Here is my function

```
export async function getMyPosts (type) {
  await api
  var myPosts = []

  const posts = await api.firestore().collection('posts').where('status', '==', 'published')
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.data())
      })
    })
    .catch(catchError)
}
```

In my main function I am getting a param called 'type'. Based on the value of that param I want to add another qhere clause to the above query. For example, `if type = 'nocomments'`, then I want to add a where clause .`where('commentCount', '==', 0)`, otherwise `if type = 'nocategories'`, then the where clause will be querying another property like `.where('tags', '==', 'none')`

I am unable to understand how to add this conditional where clause.

NOTE: in firestore you add multiple conditions by just appending your where clauses like - .`where("state", "==", "CA").where("population", ">", 1000000)` and so on.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Add the where clause to the query only when needed:

```
export async function getMyPosts (type) {
  await api
  var myPosts = []

  var query = api.firestore().collection('posts')
  if (your_condition_is_true) {  // you decide
    query = query.where('status', '==', 'published')
  }
  const questions = await query.get()
}
```

Comment: How to query = query.doc(myId) dynamically? I've tried with this example and works with **where** clause but not with **doc**.

Comment: is this still valid in new firestore? the collection, does it have a "where" method or is it through "ref" parent object?

Comment: Hi, what is "api", from where it can be imported ? I see query starting like this - const store = admin.firestore();....Is your api same as my admin ?

Comment: make sure to reassign as it is in the example
query = query.where('status', '==', 'published')
this doesnt work
var query = api.firestore().collection('posts')
  if (your_condition_is_true) {  // you decide
    query.where('status', '==', 'published')
  }

Answer (score 0):

For the frontend Web SDK:

Or you can look at this link for a different method:
[Firestore conditional where clause using Modular SDK v9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69036031/firestore-conditional-where-clause-using-modular-sdk-v9)

```js
let showPublishStatus: boolean = true

let conditionalConstraint: QueryConstraint = showPublishStatus 
? where("status", "==", "published") 
: where("status", "!=", "published")

let queryWebSDK = query(collection(db, "Collection"), conditionalConstraint)
```