# How to query data from Firestore with dynamic input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with my code and I don't know how to solve it in the correct way.

I am trying to write a filter that when user clicks on each filter, it will automatically query the data from firestore.

[image]

In my Redux Saga have this one:

```
const {type, currency, location} = action.payload;
```

All is work fine but the thing is when I trying to query the data with dynamic input:
For example:

```
firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("ItemData")
        .where("type", "==", type)
        .where('currency', '==', currency)
        .where('location', '==', location)
```

When user clicks on option `type` it shows nothing as the input `currency` and `location` have no data, just the empty string, so the query return none response. Unless you click all the filter it will show the correct response.

So how can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should only add to the query clause when needed (ie. type, currency, or location are true/not empty):

```
let query = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("ItemData");

if (type) {
    query = query.where('type', '==', type);
}

if (currency) {
    query = query.where('currency', '==', currency);
}

if (location) {
    query = query.where('location', '==', location);
}
```

Special thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48515036/4875631) which had a similar issue to yours.

Comment: But how I can do the combine query like type and currency have value?

Comment: @TonyBui That code should do what you want. For example, if they've selected a filter for type, it will filter down and select a type, otherwise it wont search type at all.

Comment: Ah yes. I understand what you mean. Thanks mate! 1 vote for you mate