# Kotlin Firestore Queries Issue

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Im using FirestorePagingAdapter in the FireStoreUI framework to create a simple query and get results into a recycler view.

I am able to fetch results and display them if I use a simple query:

```
var mQuery = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("test")
```

But in my application I have a searchView which I will be using to add queries options in mQuery eg:

```
var mQuery : Query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("test")
        if (!searchString.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            println("SearchView: $searchString")
            mQuery.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("name", searchString)
        }
```

But this does not work. 
Can we not add options to Query after it has been assigned?

Answer (score 2):

Query objects are immutable.  They can't be changed after created.  Notice from the API documentation that [whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) returns a new Query object (as well as all filters) with the new condition added to it.  So, you can just reassign `mQuery` with the new Query it built.

See also: [Conditional where clause in firestore queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48514932)