# Conditional where query on Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've tried implementing the solutions here:

[Conditional where clause in firestore queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48514932/conditional-where-clause-in-firestore-queries)

[Firestore: Multiple conditional where clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036975/firestore-multiple-conditional-where-clauses)

But they do not seem to work (see code examples below). Has Firestore changed anything? Am I messing up something in the code below?

**Thanks in advance!**

For context, the below is in a useEffect hook inside a react functional component. However, I do not believe that is relevant, as the working example below (without the conditional queries) works fine.

**Basic example - filter hard coded - works fine. The filter is applied**

```
const query = db.collection('todos')
    .where('userId', '==', userId)
    .where('status', '==', 'pending');

query.onSnapshot((res) => {
  const todos = [];
  res.forEach((todo) => {
    todos.push(todo.data());
  });
});
```

**Does NOT work - returns results that have all statuses. The where query within the IF block has not been applied**

```
const query = db.collection('todos').where('userId', '==', userId);

if (filter === 'complete') {
  query.where('status', '==', 'pending');
}
if (filter === 'complete') {
  query.where('status', '==', 'complete');
}
query.onSnapshot((res) => {
  const todos = [];
  res.forEach((todo) => {
    todos.push(todo.data());
  });
});
```

**Another example to ensure that the if block itself is not the issue here. An initial query created and a 'where' condition added after it (but before the onSnapshot). In this instance, the userId where clause is applied, however the status where clause is ignored. All status todo's are returned**

```
const query = db.collection('todos').where('userId', '==', userId);

query.where( 'status', '==', 'pending' ); // This 'where' clause is being ignored

query.onSnapshot((res) => {
  const todos = [];
  res.forEach((todo) => {
    todos.push(todo.data());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not following the pattern correctly in the [question you cited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036975/firestore-multiple-conditional-where-clauses).

You have to re-assign the query object every time you want to add a new condition.  Simply calling `where` repeatedly doesn't do what you want.  `where` returns a whole new query object every time it's called.  You have to continue building on that object, not the original one.

```
// use LET, not CONST, so you can ressign it
let query = db.collection('todos').where('userId', '==', userId);

// Reassign query, don't just call where and ignore the return value
if (filter === 'complete') {
  query = query.where('status', '==', 'pending');
}
```