# Firestore conditional where clause using Modular SDK v9

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to perform a query with conditional `where()` clause using Firebase Modular SDK (v9)?

Example query in name-spaced version (v8):

```js
const status = "live"
const publishedAfter = 1630607348811

let q = firebase.firestore().collection("articles")

// filters selected by users
if (status) q = q.where("status", "==", "live")
if (publishedAfter) q = q.where("publishedAt", ">", publishedAfter)

const qSnapshot = await q.get()
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Option 1: Conditionally adding [`QueryConstraint`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.queryconstraint) using previous as base**

```js
let q = query(collection(firestore, "articles"))

// filters selected by users
if (status) q = query(q, where("status", "==", "live"))
if (publishedAfter) q = query(q, where("publishedAt", ">", publishedAfter))

const qSnapshot = await getDocs(q);
```

**Option 2: Conditionally adding `QueryConstraints` to an array**

```js
const constraints = []

// filters selected by users
if (status) constraints.push(where("status", "==", "live"))
if (publishedAfter) constraints.push(where("publishedAt", ">", publishedAfter))

const q = query(collection(firestore, "articles"), ...constraints)

const qSnapshot = await getDocs(q);
```

Comment: Unbelievable. After 2 days cracking my skull with this and all I had to do was deconstruct the array... Thank you.

Comment: May I ask you to have a look at a Firebase related question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73953421/firebase-javascript-shows-errors-if-used-outside-the-head-tag?