# firebase javascript shows errors if used outside the head tag

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await

I am using [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) to work with Firestore database. I am just inserting a `document` in a `collection` by the method `setDoc`. It works if I use it inside the `head` tag. But if I use it outside the `head` tag, it shows errors.
The complete code follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Firebase app</title>

    <script type="module">

  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-app.js";

  import { getFirestore,collection, addDoc, getDocs, doc, setDoc } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-firestore.js"; 

  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: ".....",
    authDomain: "......firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "flutter0000",
    storageBucket: "flutter777.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "8888115",
    appId: "1:9888......"
  };
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  const db = getFirestore(app);




  await setDoc(doc(db, "cities", "Cus11"), {
    name: "111Los Angeles",
    state: "CA",
    country: "USA"
  });



  </script>

</head>
<body>


<h1>FIREBASE APP</h1>


  <!-- <script type="module"> -->
    <script>
  
  
  await setDoc(doc(db, "cities", "Cus222"), {
  name: "111Los Angeles",
  state: "CA",
  country: "USA"
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `setDoc` method inside `head` tag works. But inside the `body` tag , the `setDoc` shows the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions, async generators and modules test.php:50:2
```

If I use `<script type="module">` instead of just `<script>` inside the `body` tag, the following error shows up in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: setDoc is not defined
```

How to make the code work inside the `body` tag i.e. outside the `head` tag ?

Answer (score 2):

When declaring variables in a module, they don't get automatically declared globally, so you have to attach them to the window object by yourself.

So you have two options, attach every firebase method into window; or a better option would be to create specific functions that call these firebase method. I'll leave you an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Firebase app</title>

  <script type="module">

    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-app.js";

    import { getFirestore, collection, addDoc, getDocs, doc, setDoc } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-firestore.js";

    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: ".....",
      authDomain: "......firebaseapp.com",
      projectId: "flutter0000",
      storageBucket: "flutter777.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "8888115",
      appId: "1:9888......"
    };
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    const db = getFirestore(app);


    window.storeCities = async function (name, state, country) {
      await setDoc(doc(db, "cities", "Cus11"), {
        name,
        state,
        country 
      });
    }

    await storeCities("111Los Angeles", "CA", "USA")

  </script>

</head>

<body>


  <h1>FIREBASE APP</h1>


  <script type="module">
    await storeCities("111Los Angeles", "CA", "USA")
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Note that both scripts are "module" type.